# Help option not working after migration from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, upgrade

After migration from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010 the help option (question mark symbol on the right corner) does not work. Opens a new page and says Internet Explorer cannot display error. Help Please!!

Comment: Is this really SharePoint Foundation, or is it SharePoint Server 2010? What's the URL IE is trying to open when clicking Help?

Comment: its opening _layouts/help.aspx...it is sharepoint server 2010

Comment: What kind of upgrade approach did you use? Dit you do an "In-Place upgrade" or a "Database Attach upgrade"?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2010 Central Administration, go to System Settings > Configure Privacy Options:

Make sure the option External Web-Based Help is set to Yes (Recommended).

[image: SharePoint 2010: External Web-based Help]